# How to show the value of two related arrays in php?

Tags: php, pagination

I have two arrays myarray1 has name of images and myarray2 has the address of images, 
I am going to show image names and their addresses in pagination but do not know how to complete the code.

```
$pages = array_chunk($myarray1,10);
$addrs = array_chunk($myarray2,10);
$page_number = 1
$count = 0;
    echo'<table>';
    echo'<tr>';
    foreach ($pages[$page_number] as $i) {
      $counter++;
      if ($count == 5) {
         echo '</tr><tr>';
         $counter = 0;
      }
       echo'<td>'.$i. " AND " . <<Value of addrs array goes here
      echo'</td>';
     }
     .......
```

Comment: What about to create one array with all data?

Comment: @vaske, agree but could not find a way

Comment: where you generate those two arrays? on that place you can create one array, or you can use you approach if you are 100% sure that myarray1[1] is same in myarray2[1] than you can use it directly as you described there like $addrs[$page_number] also put $count++ at the end of foreach.

Comment: @vaske, I do not want to remove the problem want to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this: (note also the counter++ is changed in $count++)

```
foreach ($pages[$page_number] as $key => $i) {
      $count++;
      if ($count == 5) {
         echo '</tr><tr>';
         echo '</div>';
         echo '</div>';
         $count = 0;
      }
       echo'<td>'.$i. " AND " . $addrs[$page_number][$key]
      echo'</td>';
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll do it on this way

```
  $count = 1;
  foreach ($pages[$page_number] as $key => $i) {
  if ($count % 5 == 0) {
     echo '</tr><tr>';
     echo '</div>';
     echo '</div>';
  }
   echo'<td>'.$i. " AND " . $addrs[$page_number][$key]
  echo'</td>';
  $count++; // increase at the end.
 }
```

if you can try to var_dump those arrays before foreach just to be clear how structure looks like.